# Cohens d effect size calculations across 3 groups

Tags: anova, effect-size, group-differences, cohens-d

Is it possible to calculate a single Cohens d effect size, across 3 groups?

I have successfully used Cohens d to calculate the effect sizes between state 1 and 2 (as simple example given below) for all frequencies. This has allowed me to calculate the frequencies which would give the largest effect size, so I can focus on these for further analysis.

I now have a third group (3) and wondered if it was possible to calculate a combined effect size between the three groups?

[image: simplified data]

**Update - added more information 19.05.2020**

I am measuring the sound difference across an object in all third-octave frequencies every 5 minutes. The object can have three distinct states which I can change, which have a corresponding effect on the sound difference. The states are ordered, from lowest effect to highest effect (or attenuation).

My independent variable is the state and my dependent variables are the frequencies.

**What am I trying to understand?**

I am trying to determine the 'top 4' frequencies out of the 7 (in reality, there are many) with the largest effect size, for further investigation.

Hopefully, this describes the experiment, I am not sure of the hypothesis test, or the test statistic.

Comment: The effect size depends on the planned experimental design, the hypothesis test, and the test statistic: please provide that information.

Comment: Hi @whuber, I have added some more information to the original question. I don't have all the answers, but hopefully, you can understand what I am trying to achieve, with the context of the additional information?

Comment: You might be using "effect size" in a different way than implied by Cohen's d.  Are you perhaps just trying to find the frequencies with the highest average values of your observations?

Comment: I am trying to find the frequencies with the largest difference in means between groups and the smallest variation in data within each group. Which was where the Cohens d worked well for 2 groups, now I have 3 groups, I am not sure what to use.

Comment: Where you write "and" you are imposing an impossible condition, because (except in rare lucky cases) you cannot achieve both objectives.

Comment: Absolutely, and Cohens d offered a weighted method for this.

Comment: It's not at all clear those are suitable weights, though.  What *is* clear is that plenty of other weights can be compatible with your objective.  The need to consider this comes to the fore when you have to evaluate more than two variables, as you have discovered.

Comment: Are you able to suggest any areas for further research? I have read around this subject, and subject to more investigation, i think a one way ANOVA might yield the answers I need?

Comment: Yes, that's right, perhaps followed by Tukey's HSD.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!